# cannot have a variable as phpmailer to address

Tags: phpmailer, php

I'm trying to use phpmailer to send emails to addresses stored in the variable $to like this

```
$mail->AddAddress($to);
```

but I keep getting an error message saying this

```
You must provide at least one recipient email address.
```

I have tried printing $to and it prints out the correct email address where I want the message to be sent. The mail gets sent if I put in an email address (e.g. test1@gmail.com) instead of $to. Could anyone help? Thanks!

This is the context:

```
// if the email seller form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

// retreive the seller's email using his id
$seller_id = $_GET["sellerid"];

// query for the seller's email
$user_query = query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?", $seller_id);
$to = $user_query[0]["username"];   

// send an email to the seller
require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

// instantiate mailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// use your ISP's SMTP server
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.fas.harvard.edu";

// set From:
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['buyer_email']);

// set To:
$mail->AddAddress($to);

// set Subject:
$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];

// set body
$mail->Body = $_POST['message'];

// set alternative body, in case user's mail client doesn't support HTML
$mail->AltBody = "Please view this message in an HTML-enabled browser.";

// send mail
if ($mail->Send() === false)
    die($mail->ErrorInfo . "\n");
```

This is the query function

```
    /**
* Executes SQL statement, possibly with parameters, returning
* an array of all rows in result set or false on (non-fatal) error.
*/
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
{
// SQL statement
$sql = func_get_arg(0);

// parameters, if any
$parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

// try to connect to database
static $handle;
if (!isset($handle))
{
    try
    {
        // connect to database
        $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
        $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // trigger (big, orange) error
        trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }
}

// prepare SQL statement
$statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
if ($statement === false)
{
    // trigger (big, orange) error
    trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
    exit;
}

// execute SQL statement
$results = $statement->execute($parameters);

// return result set's rows, if any
if ($results !== false)
{
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: var_dump($to) returns string 'test@gmail.com' (length=14)

Comment: actually, no. I tried var_dump($to) before the very first if condition, and it returned an email address. But inside the if condition, it returned NULL. Why is this?

Comment: Can you try var_dump() just after $to = $user_query[0]["username"];?

Comment: So its clear that the email is never fetched from database. I hope you are printing PHP errors as the function query may be returning false and you are not seeing the error when you are accessing it. Another reason may be that in database you have NULL for that username.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the form's action is <form method="post" action="email_seller.php"> and so when the submit button is hit on the form, the page that loads can't execute the command $seller_id = $_GET["sellerid"] How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is...

```
// if the email seller form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")  //<--   POST HERE
{

// retreive the seller's email using his id
$seller_id = $_GET["sellerid"];            //<--   GET HERE
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that the form's action is <form method="post" action="email_seller.php"> and so when the submit button is hit on the form, the page that loads can't execute the command $seller_id = $_GET["sellerid"] How can I fix this?

Comment: From best idea to less best: 1. Save the `sellerid` in a session variable between pages. 2. Put the sellerid in a hidden form field. 3. Include `?sellerid=20` in the form's `target`, ie: `<form name='thing' method='post' target='somepage.php?sellerid=20'>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try the first approach.